# How to define a shape of object in typescript ? Should we do it with classes or interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I'm developing backend application in typescript. I want to define shape of an object. From typescript, I have options like classes, interfaces, types. Which one should I use?

Below are the docs recommending interfaces to define shapes.

`https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html`,

The below document says, its better to use interface on types

`https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?e=83#example/types-vs-interfaces`

they recommend using interfaces to define the shape of an object. But, we can't instantiate an interface, and interfaces cannot hold data.

On the other hand, we have classes that define shape/blueprint of the object and can hold data.

So, should I go with classes to define shape and initialize it where ever I want?

where exactly should I user interfaces then, considering classes do all the work? What is the use-case of interfaces?

Please help me.

Comment: IMO classes are only suitable when you want to link together *data* with *methods* that operate on that data. If you don't have methods bundled with the data, only data itself, it feels more natural to me to use an `interface` or a `type` to describe the shape of the data. I prefer `type`s, but they're mostly interchangeable.

Comment: Added to this, interfaces don't hold data themselves, but they do define the shape of an object that can hold data. You will often use interfaces for things you pass around to make sure that you are sending what the receiver expects to get.

Comment: so, if i want to create an object of type `animal` (`animal` is an interface) ,  how would I do ? 

Will it be `let obj = {} as animal`  ? will I get all nested attributes of animal interface ?

@CertainPerformance @Cehhiro

Comment: Actually, with the style of TS code I write ([examples](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts)), I don't often find defining types for expressions to be necessary, except at the edges of the script where there's untyped input (like from an API) that needs to be asserted to be of the proper type. TS's automatic type inference is *usually* sufficient - eg `const dog = { legs: 4 }` is automatically inferred to be `{ legs: number }` without having to do something like `const dog: animal`